# NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query? google fusion tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am wondering what is wrong in my code to be producing the following error message:
NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?

I believe that I am properly referencing the new SQL V1 API and the tables I am referencing are base tables that allow data to be exported.

Code Snippet

```
function getEcoliData(beachID) {
//local namespace
var rows = [];
var items = [];

var queryURL = "http://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=";
var queryTail = '&jsonCallback=?';
var whereClause = "WHERE 'Beach_ID' = " + beachID;
var query = "SELECT 'Sample_Date', 'Average_E.coli_Density','Recreational_Water_Quality_Guideline' FROM 1-ZORhnuDELDxO1FsmzJ60K3JzWOYOKvsHibrQeo " + whereClause + " ORDER BY 'Sample_Date' DESC";
var queryText = encodeURI(query);

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: queryURL + queryText + queryTail,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    success: function (data) {
        rows = data.tables.rows;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            items.push(rows[i]);
        }
        return items;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Data is not available for this location at the present time, please check back at a later time. Thank you.");
    }
});
```

}

any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

use `https://` instead of `http://` . You also need to send a valid key via the URL(be sure that you've activated the Fusion-Tables-API-service inside the [API-console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) before you use the key).

Comment: thanks for the response, however, I had no success with changing the protocol nor setting an API key in the URL string. I enabled this service as well. I still receive the same error  message.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/CEgqw/  (I've fixed some other issues with the code, but they are not related to the 403-error)

Comment: It looks like a spoke too soon on this. I have another issue, I am now getting the following message: NetworkError: 407 Proxy Authentication Required. I am behind a proxy but from i can tell the proxy is working. I can access the jsfiddle above and other google maps hosted in our environment.Any thoughts or suggestions are once again appreciated. Michael